# How do I import a Github repository into Nodeclipse (Enide)?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I've got Nodeclipse (Enide Studio) up and running, and I can edit code and run a simple "Hello World" Node.js app from within Enide. However, I can't figure out how to import a Node.js project from Github into Enide and run it under the "Node" perspective. Can someone enlighten me as to the steps?

Comment: Install the EGit plugin, it comes with several features like importing a Git repository to your current (Node) perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run 

`npm install -g nodeclipse`

And from the source code directory run 

`nodeclipse -p`

After this you can import as normal project:
File -> Import -> General / Existing Projects into Workspace

Comment: Although I received this answer after I figured it out, this is exactly the method I have been using.

Comment: which location do i run npm install -g nodeclipse

Answer (score 0):

Correct names are Nodeclipse and Enide Studio.

This is not actually related to Nodeclipse project.

With EGit you can File -> Import -> Git -> Project from Git

or use CLI `git clone`,

then you `nodeclipse -p` from project folder.

Finally in Eclipse or Enide Studio File -> Import -> General -> Existing project into Workspace.

Comment: I think this question does relate to the Nodeclipse project. It's about how to get *Nodeclipse* to import a Github project, and not, say, JetBrains Webstorm.

Comment: OK, there is general import for any project, that @user2964909 has already given.